# How to wait for bootstrap modal animation to finish in Vue jest test

Tags: jquery, testing, vue.js, jestjs, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to wait for modal animation to finish in Vue jest test? My problem is that when I click on the button (button.add_modal), div.my-modal should get a class "show", but after triggering my button, seems that the class isn't attached in my html (in jest test), in dev tools in works fine.

```
    wrapper.find('button.add_modal').trigger('click');
    //This should return true, but I'm getting false.
    expect(wrapper.contains('div#my-modal.show')).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We faced a similar issue with testing a component that contains a [BootstrapVue modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/). I found something that worked by looking at the [BV modal unit tests](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/modal/modal.spec.js) themselves. In there, you'll see the following repeated throughout:

```
// take action to open modal and then
await waitNT(wrapper.vm)
await waitRAF()
await waitNT(wrapper.vm)
await waitRAF()
```

...where `waitNT` and `waitRF` are defined in [tests/utils.js](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/tests/utils.js):

```
export const waitNT = ctx => new Promise(resolve => ctx.$nextTick(resolve))
export const waitRAF = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve))
```

This allows the DOM updates to finish and the modal to "appear" in your test. You may need to fiddle with the number of times you call them. You'll see them repeated in the [BV unit tests](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/modal/modal.spec.js) anywhere from 1-3 times after a modal open is triggered.

One other useful item is stubbing out the transitions in your wrapper mount, e.g.:

```
wrapper.mount(MyModalComponent, {
  stubs: {
    transition: false
  }
}
```

This ensures that transitions happen synchronously instead of async, as [detailed in the docs here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/components/#transitionstub).